# How to use input element in select element?

Tags: javascript, html, select, input

I am trying to add input element into a select element.My code that is not working is like following;

```
<select size="<%= myCollection.length %>" id="functionList">               
    <% for(var i=0; i<myCollection.length; i++){ %>
        <option>
            <input class="myInput" id="<%= i %>" name="<%= myCollection[i].name %>"></input>
        </option>
    <% } %>
</select>
```

Comment: This is not valid HTML.

Comment: Is this your complete code?

Comment: @Barmar it's a template obviously

Comment: Sorry, but you can't have input-elements inside a select-element.

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović I meant that the HTML it's generating isn't valid because you can't have input inside option.

Comment: You should set the value of the option on the option element, and it will not honor the class. You probably want something like: `<option value="<%= i %>"><%= myCollection[i].name %</option>`.

Comment: @some The line gives me a selectable string line but I want to set input value in the line.

Comment: @MeseleŞuki I would like to fly like superman, but that's not going to happen. And you can't have input-elements inside a select. It's not possible. You can have as many input elements you want, but they can not be inside the select-element. You need to rethink how to solve what you are trying to do. Maybe if you describe what you want to do, we can give you some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it wouldn’t be valid HTML to have an `input` within an `option`.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Therefore, you would not be able to do that with existing HTML components — you would need you create your own custom component and style it to look like a drop down with inputs as options.

I’d consider the UX and accessibility of that component as well.